# wordpress add_action() issue in ajax call

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, ajax, javascript

After a hole day finding solution for the issue, i didn't get what is exactly i am making the mistake. Please give your valuable answer for my issue and humble request not to block if you can't answer.

so i am trying Ajax Call in WordPress and getting issue "Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in C:\xampp\htdocs\brandcart\wp-content\themes\twentyten\functions.php on line 51"

WordPress : 4.1.1 Theme : Twenty-ten

Here is my code:

in Twenty-ten page.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="GreetingAll" id="GreetingAll" value="Hello Everyone!" />
    <input type="submit" id="PleasePushMe" />
 <div id="test-div1">
 </div>
```

in Twenty-ten functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_myjavascript' );
function add_myjavascript(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-implementation.js', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/script/ajax-implementation.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
  }
 // creating Ajax call for WordPress  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction22' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction22' );    
  function MyAjaxFunction22(){
  //get the data from ajax() call
   $GreetingAll = $_POST['GreetingAll '];
   $results = "<h2>".$GreetingAll."</h2>";
  // Return the String
   die($results);
  }
```

and my ajax-implementation.js (which is in script directory in the theme)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var GreetingAll = jQuery("#GreetingAll").val();
jQuery("#PleasePushMe").click(function(){ jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/brandcart/wp-content/themes/twentyten/functions.php',
  data: {
  action: 'MyAjaxFunction',
  GreetingAll: GreetingAll,
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
  jQuery("#test-div1").html('');
  jQuery("#test-div1").append(data);
  },
  error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert(errorThrown);
  }
  });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending your AJAX request to the wrong place.  Of course calling `functions.php` directly will get you undefined function errors, because the WordPress API isn't loaded by `functions.php` ( it's the other way round ). A car doesn't make fuel go forward, fuel makes a car go forward, simply getting in the car won't make fuel magically appear, in the same way loading `functions.php` won't magically make all the WordPress APIs appear.

Also, using files in your theme as AJAX and form submission endpoints is a huge security hole. Even if you change theme, those endpoints are still there, and can still be used.

So instead, use the official ajax endpoint:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

When you enqueue your script, also localise a variable to pass the url of the endpoint to your javascript:

```
// in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Then in your javascript, the endpoint will be:

```
ajax_object.ajax_url
```

### A final note

All your work will be destroyed on the next update of twentyten. Instead of modifying the twentyten theme, create a child theme and put your modifications there. This way you can update the default themes without loosing any changes